# Login.php redirects to same homepage with different elements

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, redirect

I have a login.php page that takes a username and password, verifies that the username and password exists in the database and then redirects the user to the homepage.html

if the user isn't logged in then the homepage.html will only have nav links to other pages. when the user has logged in then the same homepage.html will have different nav links.

this is the current homepage.html

```
<body>
<div id="nav"> 
<ul>
    <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="registration.php">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="fflogin.php">Frequent Flyer Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="adminlogin.php">Admin Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="terms&con.html">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
</ul>
```

this is what i want after logging in

```
<body>
<div id="nav"> 
<ul>
    <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="changeBooking.php">Change Booking</a></li>
    <li><a href="booking.php">Booking</a></li>
    <li><a href="terms&con.html">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
</ul>
```

the above is supposed to be dynamic links
I know that i can make a new homepage and redirect to that 1 after logging in, but i prefer not to

Comment: So where is your PHP code where you're trying to do it?

Comment: _"the above is supposed to be dynamic links"_ - HTML doesn't do dynamic by itself, that's what PHP (and other) languages are for, HTML is MOSTLY used as the "display" tool, not generating content. - and without either having apache / .htaccess doing some magic on your .html file so it can execute php, you don't have much of a choice.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you have provided yourself you could do something as basic as this:

```
if($logged_in){
    //LOGGED IN MENU
}else{
    //NOT LOGGED IN MENU
}
```

The `$logged_in` variable obviously needs to be changed to match the way you check if a user is logged in.

This is all very basic php and I would suggest you'd find a guide or tutorial with google and learn a bit.

As far as the .html file goes, the above code obviously won't work out of the box without getting the server / apache / .htaccess doing some magic. (See the comments under Markus AO's answer).

So I would suggest you display the html content on the homepage.php, otherwise you can redirect to two different html pages as such:

```
if($logged_in){
    header('Location:www.url.com/homeLoggedIn.html');
    die();
}else{
    header('Location:www.url.com/homeNotLoggedIn.html');
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your homepage.html is a static page, you can't do anything in PHP to change it, for the obvious reason that PHP is not parsed on that page.

You may want to do something like this (for the most rudimentary approach):

1. Change your homepage to homepage.php so it's parsed for PHP code. (Edit: Alternatively configure Apache to parse .html files for PHP code.)
2. Create two files with just the menu html; e.g. menu_guest.html and menu_member.html.
3. Replace your menu section in homepage.php with the following.

`if ($logged_in === false) include 'menu_guest.html';`

`else include 'menu_member.html';`

Change the condition above to match whatever your login script uses to tell the system that a user has been validated. Probably a `$_SESSION` variable. Basic PHP stuff. What did you try so far yourself?

Comment: @1. this is not right, also .htm .html .jpg .xxx can be parsed for PHP code

Comment: @donald123 Anything can be parsed for PHP of course. Just need a .htaccess / Apache rule for that. Without it, PHP can't work from within your static content. Those sorts of parsing rules create unnecessary overhead though. Imagine if you unnecessarily parsed every multi-megapixel jpeg file for PHP code, just because you need one of them so parsed. Would lead to funky performance.

Comment: It has to be an html page. so i cannot change it into php

Comment: Then your options are either configuring Apache to parse .html files for PHP code; or redirecting to a different page.